# OpenSUSE multicast not working?

Tags: applet, multicast, opensuse

I'm trying to do multicast dns on OpenSuSE through a trusted java applet<->, and my attempts to find anything on the network are silently blocked! What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSUSE won't tell you during installation, but it enabled a firewall by default that will block multicast operations. You will have to disable the two firewall services to get multicast working properly, namely

```
SuSEfirewall2_setup
```

and

```
SuSEfirewall2_init
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is indeed the firewall (as pointed out by Stefan Kendall).  If you wish to fix this without disabling the firewall, use a different zone to the default.  The "home" zone, for example, does not have this restriction (or at least my install of OpenSUSE Tumbleweed did not).  I believe that NetworkManager should allow you to select a firewall zone on a per-network basis.

EDIT: the "internal" zone should also work.  "YaST Firewall" can be used to confirm which zones will work and also enable it in other zones (look for "mdns").